# Custom eslint no-restricted-imports for lodash vs. lodash/fp

Tags: javascript, lodash, eslint

I'm trying to define a list of certain lodash methods that should be imported from fp.
In addition, I'm trying to disallow importing from lodash's top-level.
Should disallow destructured imports from lodash.

Here's the goal:

```
import _ from 'lodash'; // should show message "Import [module] from lodash/[module] instead"
import { isEqual } from 'lodash'; // should show message "Import [module] from lodash/[module] instead"
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEqual'; // should pass
import set from 'lodash/set'; // should show message "Import [module] from lodash/fp/[module] instead"
```

eslintrc.json

```
"no-restricted-imports": [
   "error",
   {
      "patterns": [
         {
            "group": ["lodash/set"],
            "message": "Import [module] from lodash/fp/[module] instead"
         },
         {
            "group": ["lodash", "!lodash/*"],
            "message": "Import [module] from lodash/[module] instead"
         }
      ]
   }
],
```

These are the flags/patterns I've been working with. I've tried toggling the negative matchers on and off, and switched the order of the group array strings, and the groups themselves. Unable to get the desired eslint errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
"no-restricted-imports": [
   "error",
   {
      "paths": [
         {
            "name": "lodash",
            "message": "Import [module] from lodash/[module] instead"
         }
      ],
      "patterns": [
         {
            "group": ["lodash/set"],
            "message": "Import [module] from lodash/fp/[module] instead"
         }
      ]
   }
],
```